# Kafka Streams application Endless rebalancing

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

We are running a kafka streams application and stuck with a strange problem. We are using both global state store and multiple other state stores.

Our application has loaded all the data and state stores has good amount of information in it now. Now, when we tried to bring down the application and bring it back again (some config changes), it is going into endless rebalancing .. To verify we reverted back config changes, but it it still stuck in that stage. There are no erros, etc

```
INFO  o.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams - stream-client [app-1f6b14fc-685c-49fb-83c0-54e15bca15cb] Started Streams client
INFO  o.a.k.s.p.internals.StreamThread - stream-thread [app-1f6b14fc-685c-49fb-83c0-54e15bca15cb-StreamThread-2] State transition from RUNNING to PARTITIONS_REVOKED
INFO  o.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams - stream-client [app-1f6b14fc-685c-49fb-83c0-54e15bca15cb] State transition from RUNNING to REBALANCING
INFO  o.a.k.s.p.internals.StreamThread - stream-thread [app-1f6b14fc-685c-49fb-83c0-54e15bca15cb-StreamThread-2] partition revocation took 1 ms.
    suspended active tasks: []
    suspended standby tasks: []
INFO  o.a.k.s.p.internals.StreamThread - stream-thread [app-1f6b14fc-685c-49fb-83c0-54e15bca15cb-StreamThread-1] State transition from RUNNING to PARTITIONS_REVOKED
INFO  o.a.k.s.p.internals.StreamThread - stream-thread [app-1f6b14fc-685c-49fb-83c0-54e15bca15cb-StreamThread-1] partition revocation took 0 ms.
    suspended active tasks: []
    suspended standby tasks: []
04:02:13.682 6985 [main] INFO  com..... - Started Application in 6.647 seconds (JVM running for 7.484)
04:02:23.300 16603 [app-1f6b14fc-685c-49fb-83c0-54e15bca15cb-StreamThread-1] INFO  o.a.k.s.p.internals.StreamThread - stream-thread [app-1f6b14fc-685c-49fb-83c0-54e15bca15cb-StreamThread-1] State transition from PARTITIONS_REVOKED to PARTITIONS_ASSIGNED
04:02:23.300 16603 [app-1f6b14fc-685c-49fb-83c0-54e15bca15cb-StreamThread-2] INFO  o.a.k.s.p.internals.StreamThread - stream-thread [app-1f6b14fc-685c-49fb-83c0-54e15bca15cb-StreamThread-2] State transition from PARTITIONS_REVOKED to PARTITIONS_ASSIGNED
04:02:23.328 16631 [app-1f6b14fc-685c-49fb-83c0-54e15bca15cb-StreamThread-1] INFO  o.a.k.s.p.internals.StreamThread - stream-thread [app-1f6b14fc-685c-49fb-83c0-54e15bca15cb-StreamThread-1] partition assignment took 28 ms.
    current active tasks: [0_0, 1_0, 2_0, 3_0, 4_0, 5_0, 6_0, 7_5, 8_5, 9_5, 10_5, 12_4, 13_4, 14_4, 15_4, 16_4, 17_4, 19_3, 20_3, 21_3, 22_3, 23_3, 24_3, 25_3, 29_0]
    current standby tasks: [0_2]
    previous active tasks: []

04:02:23.328 16631 [app-1f6b14fc-685c-49fb-83c0-54e15bca15cb-StreamThread-2] INFO  o.a.k.s.p.internals.StreamThread - stream-thread [app-1f6b14fc-685c-49fb-83c0-54e15bca15cb-StreamThread-2] partition assignment took 28 ms.
    current active tasks: [0_3, 1_3, 2_3, 3_3, 4_3, 5_3, 7_2, 8_2, 9_2, 10_2, 12_1, 13_1, 14_1, 15_1, 16_1, 17_1, 19_0, 20_0, 21_0, 22_0, 23_0, 24_0, 25_0, 26_0]
    current standby tasks: [0_5]
    previous active tasks: []
04:03:47.602 100905 [http-nio-8080-exec-10] INFO  c.j.d.r.b.p.base.StreamsRestService - State of Kafka Streams Application: REBALANCING
04:03:49.356 102659 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] INFO  c.j.d.r.b.p.base.StreamsRestService - State of Kafka Streams Application: REBALANCING
04:03:51.600 104903 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] INFO  c.j.d.r.b.p.base.StreamsRestService - State of Kafka Streams Application: REBALANCING
04:03:53.356 106659 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] INFO  c.j.d.r.b.p.base.StreamsRestService - State of Kafka Streams Application: REBALANCING
```

```
Number of topics - 100
Partitions per topic - 6.  (7 topics with 1 partition only)
kubernetes env - 3 pods ( 2 stream threads )
```

When we try to list consumer group using following command

```
root@bastion-0:/app/confluent-5.2.2/bin# ./kafka-consumer-groups --describe --group app  --bootstrap-server kafka-0..local:9094 --command-config /app/client-sasl-ssl.properties --members

CONSUMER-ID                                                                                               HOST                    CLIENT-ID                                                            #PARTITIONS     
app-b8c729c9-dc1c-457b-8120-457035e84e58-StreamThread-1-consumer-3b370697-e737-411c-af28-fb04cfbae1dd 1.1.1.1/1.1.1.1 app-b8c729c9-dc1c-457b-8120-457035e84e58-StreamThread-1-consumer 45              
app-aaef2f83-d51c-4b6f-bbd8-616db988bd33-StreamThread-2-consumer-3edb3e5f-9f1a-499f-8732-6cd2c8b96c96 2.2.2.2/2.2.2.2 app-aaef2f83-d51c-4b6f-bbd8-616db988bd33-StreamThread-2-consumer 45              
app-1f6b14fc-685c-49fb-83c0-54e15bca15cb-StreamThread-1-consumer-00e24df4-5669-4e2c-a775-8f6c4f689714 3.3.3.3/3.3.3.3 app-1f6b14fc-685c-49fb-83c0-54e15bca15cb-StreamThread-1-consumer 46              
app-b8c729c9-dc1c-457b-8120-457035e84e58-StreamThread-2-consumer-1b6b2955-5dfd-4be7-8ad9-9f1b54fe6310 1.1.1.1/1.1.1.1 app-b8c729c9-dc1c-457b-8120-457035e84e58-StreamThread-2-consumer 45              
app-aaef2f83-d51c-4b6f-bbd8-616db988bd33-StreamThread-1-consumer-72cd0319-8ca7-493c-891d-3022b235ea01 2.2.2.2/2.2.2.2 app-aaef2f83-d51c-4b6f-bbd8-616db988bd33-StreamThread-1-consumer 45              
app-1f6b14fc-685c-49fb-83c0-54e15bca15cb-StreamThread-2-consumer-c1a16d64-8d49-4758-ab64-2af3cd9aef0f 3.3.3.3/3.3.3.3 app-1f6b14fc-685c-49fb-83c0-54e15bca15cb-StreamThread-2-consumer 45
```

The output of the above command keeps on changing - from 0 to some variable number. Ideally it should become stable after some time.

Are there any tunables/configs for kafka streams balancing (rebalancing)

Questions:

1. What causes application to rebalance endlessly while starting (even though there are no errors/exception, etc).
2. Is there any tunables which can help us avoid rebalancing ?

Comment: If there are lots of consumers then when you bring them all down or up, each one can cause a rebalance. Not sure if that is the problem in your case but sounds like it could be - the only thing that can cause a rebalance is a change in group membership or a change in number of partitions, and group membership change only happens if a new consumer joins the group or one is considered to have left  by either heartbeat stopping (ie actually shut down) or taking too long to process a polled batch of records.

Comment: The main question as elaborate by @Chris already is, _why_ is a rebalance triggered. Given your description is seems that all threads are running, and thus you don't add/remove member from the group. If that hold up, it seems that consumer drop out of the group either hitting `session.timeout.ms` or `max.poll.interval.ms` limit -- inspecting the broker and streams logs should help to verify this; there would be log statements that a member is removed from the group broker side and log statements client side that the application dropped out of the group and tries to rejoin.

Comment: You can try to increase the one or other (or even both) timeouts. -- As an alternative, you could try to upgrade brokers and clients to 2.4.0 and use the new "static group membership" feature that is designed with heavy state application (and Kubernetes deployments) in mind: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-345%3A+Introduce+static+membership+protocol+to+reduce+consumer+rebalances

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax. Thanks. I have added the logs in the question above. The stream client stays in rebalancing state for a very long time. What causes stream client to be in rebalancing even though the stream threads have transitioned to 'PARTITIONS_ASSIGNED'

Comment: If you have multiple threads, the Streams client stays in state REBALANCING as long as not all threads go to state RUNNING. And threads only go to RUNNING state after state store restoration finished. To get more insights, the underlying consumer logs would be required though. Or just try to bump the timeouts to avoid that a consumer drops out of the group? Or do you have some external monitoring in place that waits for the Streams client to reach RUNNING state and it hits a timeout and restart the POD? For this case, you should change this monitoring and not restart PODs too aggressively.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax : I went through your talk https://www.confluent.io/kafka-summit-lon19/everything-you-wanted-to-know-kafka-afraid.  It explains the concepts in a very comprehensive way.  Thanks again.  One question though, if we use static group membership with kubernetes pods, we may need to forgo auto pod scaling

Comment: Not sure if I understand you question? But there is a talk about Kafka Stream on Kubernetes that should help: https://www.confluent.io/kafka-summit-sf18/deploying-kafka-streams-applications

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax: thanks again. In the talk you mentioned about log.segment.bytes. I think one of the reason why out application is spending a lot of time recovering from state is default value of log.segment.bytes(1G). But how do we change the properties of changelog topics(created automatically by kafka streams). I don't want to make a change which is at kafka broker level.

Comment: If a topic was already create by Kafka Streams you can only modify it broker side (note, it's a per-topic conifg!). You can also set topic config in Kafka Streams via `topic.` prefix -- those config will be applied when internal topics are _created_ (cf https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-7803)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at the logs you have added, the consumer pod is starting up and so I guess maybe there is a rolling restart of the other 2 pods and hence a rebalance each time one stops and one starts.

Although Kafka is fast when running rebalance is not fast as there is chat across the group during the process - although partitions may be assigned to one consumer, the group only starts consuming when all consumers have had their assignment, and the discovery of assignment only happens within the poll method (see https://chrisg23.blogspot.com/2020/02/why-is-pausing-kafka-consumer-so.html).

Hence the way to speed up the process is to poll more frequently so that you get to hear about changes quicker, but there is a trade off - if in normal running the topics are not busy then there will be a lot of spinning doing nothing.

However, you are not quite clear on what you mean by endlessly. If you mean that the application is literally only rebalancing then see my comment above. It may be that pods are going up and down continuously (heartbeats dying) or else polling is taking a long time - are you doing a lot of I/O for each record? Restarts would be obvious from the logs and the pod names. Excessive polling would also cause warning messages suggesting you either increase `max.poll.interval.ms` or reduce `max.poll.records`